# weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, weblogic12c

I am deploying a WAR file to WebLogic server and getting following error.

While checking different response from different site. It seems everybody has responded that the commons-logging-1.1.1.jar file is not there in the CLASSPATH environment variable. Till now I have ensured that it is there in the classpath and appearing while starting through `startNodemanager.cmd`.

**Error synopsis from nodemanager log file**

`####<Aug 10, 2016 4:19:36 PM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <LT035474> <NW_OIPA_LAB> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1470826176306> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "18531030684790" for task "4". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:`

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log "
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
    at
```

`weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)`
    `at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
at`

```
weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
        at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:40)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:357)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:318)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:80)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:186)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:50)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
        at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getFields(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:1104)
        at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getFields(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:1112)
        at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getFields(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:1097)
        at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:102)
        at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.J2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(J2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:39)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessor.processServlet(WebAnnotationProcessor.java:449)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processServlets(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:210)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationsInWebXml(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:196)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:103)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.processAnnotations(WebAppModule.java:1804)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:764)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:295)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:285)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:109)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
        at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:40)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

> `

Comment: Check for duplicate jars. Maybe this jar already exists inside your WAR's lib.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue has been resolved. Infact my CLASSPATH environment variable for the concerned jar file was wrong.